# mysqli_insert_id() vs Stored procedure for insert in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created a registration table which inserts user info into the database in multiple tables related using primary key, I am currently using mysqli_insert_id() which is working well, but i saw a video on youtube with the person using stored procedure to do this. He calls it in the php Mysql query and passing the variables from $_POST as arguments.

I would like to know if the way i do it with the mysqli_insert_id() will work well or its best to do it the stored procedure way?

Comment: I am eating my soup with a spoon. But I saw on youtube someone eating a soup with chopsticks. I would like to know if the way to eat with a spoon  will work well or its best to do so with chopsticks?

Comment: why so harsh please give me a break. I just wanted some advice, but you are funny.

Comment: @lee Random YouTube videos are the worst place to get advice for database programming. They're about as scary as "do it yourself open-heart surgery and save BIG $$$$$". The biggest problem here is you didn't link to the video, and you didn't show the code.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSS_VeEGzJQ thats the link to the video.

Comment: My aim was to tell that mysqli_insert_id() (a spoon) is all right, despite what you seen somewhere.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh I get it now thanks very much, although the analogy was very funny. :)